# Which one is the true statement: $B \subseteq A-(A-B)$ or $A-(A-B) \subseteq B$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Which one is the true statement: "$B \subseteq A-(A-B)$" or "$A-(A-B) \subseteq B$" ?

I think the former is true but I'm not sure here could someone provide some advice?

Thank you

Comment: You mixed / with \

Comment: A quick way to guess the true one is noticing that $A- X$, whatever $X$ is, is *always* a subset of $A$. So: can the first one be aways true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To see what’s going on, you can make a [Venn diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venn_diagram):

[image]

The blue region represents $A\setminus B$; if you subtract that from $A$ to get $A\setminus(A\setminus B)$, what’s left is the red region. The picture now makes it pretty clear that $A\setminus(A\setminus B)\subseteq B$, but since the white region need not be empty, it isn’t necessarily true that $B\subseteq A\setminus(A\setminus B)$.

Once you’ve used the Venn diagram to decide which statement is always true, you can then try to prove the statement more formally.

Answer (score 2):

Note that you have the identity 
$A-(A-B)=A\cap B$.

Comment: Ah so the latter statement of $A-(A-B) \subseteq B$ is the true one correct ?

Comment: Yes, you got it.

Answer (score 0):

$A-(A-B)= A\cap (A \cap B^c)^c
= A\cap (A^c \cup B) =( A\cap A^c) \cup ( A \cap B) = \phi \cup ( A \cap B ) = A \cap B$
And $A \cap B$ is subset of  $B$ .

Comment: This is not correct. You should have a union between $A^C$ and $B^C$:
$$A-(A-B)=A-(A\cap B^C)=A\cap (A\cap B^C)^C=A\cap (A^C \cup B)=(A\cap A^C) \cup (A\cap B)=A\cap B.$$

Comment: @kccu ues i misunderstood i correct it

Answer (score 0):

`it can be done two cases, firstly if you assume that B$\subset$A,it would be second one true.Because A-(A-B)=$A^c\cap B$.And also other side if you assume that  A$\subset$B,again would be second one true,therefore A-(A-B)$\subset$B